# PHP while loop with HTML

Tags: php, html, css, blogs

I want to make some mini-blog using php, the code is next:

```
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array ($fetch)) {
echo '<div class="content-posts">';
echo $row['bio'] ;

'</div>';
}
```

the .content-posts Div is width:800px; and height 250px;
and I have them 5x echoed. but they go one over another (please check picture to see how it looks)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJaPk.png

As you can see on picture, not only that divs go one over another, but also every next post goes a bit to the right, duo to border. if I delete border in CSS, they will be in same vertical line, but they will still be one over another.

can anyone suggest me proper code? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any css code?

Comment: Please put more effort into debugging next time.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, here is the fiddle file: http://jsfiddle.net/h1gauaph/

What I'm trying to archive is this .content-posts divs under each other. and you can see in picture from orginal post they go one over another.

Answer (score 5):

```
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array ($fetch)) {
    echo '<div class="content-posts">';
    echo $row['bio'] ;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

should work. Check the error-output settings of your PHP configuration. Your code above should result at least in a warning.

Comment: So this code is fine, but rest of my php code should be checked, if I recall you correct?